# Animate resultant href given its name?

Tags: jquery

Sorry folks I had posted a question earlier that probably did not make a lot of sense.  So I deleted it and am going to retry posting it.

I have a link that when clicked navigates the user to a specific part of the page (This part works great).  However, I want that "specific" part of the page (namely an a href link) to animate so that the user's eyes pay attention to it.

So I have something like this:

`<a href="#" name="myapp" class="app">click me</a>`

Basically with this I have a click event in jquery which is called on any href with the class name `app` as follows:

```
$(".app").click(function (e) {
                var name = this.name;
                scrollToAnchor(name);
                e.preventDefault();
            });
```

This is working great, the user clicks the link and it calls this function which calls a `scrollToAnchor(name)` function.  Now after the scrollToAnchor function I would like to animate the object it points to (namely name).  So imagine at the top of a site I have that href that I posted above.  And at somewhere near the bottom of the site I have another href:

`<a href="someURL" name="myapp">Some Site</a>`

So when I click the first a href it scrolls me to this anchor tag.  That part is working but I'd like to animate this second anchor tag background.  If I try this:

```
$(".app").click(function (e) {
                var name = this.name;
                scrollToAnchor(name);
                $(this).animate({
                    backgroundColor: "#FFD700"
                },
                    2500,
                    function () {
                        $(this).animate({ backgroundColor: "#fff" }, 2500);
                    });
                e.preventDefault();
            });
```

That wont work as that animates the initial anchor tag the one I posted at the top of this question.  I want to animate the anchor tag that it scrolls to (the one that holds the `name` variable).  Can I somehow do that without hard coding it by an ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `$(this)` selector when animating.  `$(this)` in this instance would be the control that activated the click event.

You should change this to something like the following, where you are specifically loading the required element.

```
$(".app").click(function (e) {
    var name = this.name;
    scrollToAnchor(name);
    var target = $('a[href="#' + this.name + '"]');
    target.animate({
         backgroundColor: "#FFD700"
      },
      2500,
      function () {
         target.animate({ backgroundColor: "#fff" }, 2500);
      }
    );

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Getting an error...Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [="tkpc"].  Looks to be an issue with the way you set this part up: `var target = $('a[href="#' + this.name + '"]');`

Comment: `$('a[href="#' + this.name + '"]');` needs to be customised to your requirements.  It should be a jquery selector that uniquely identified the element you are navigating to.  I have done this with `href` but you can use `name` or `id` or whatever else.

Comment: Here's what I have `$(".app").click(function (e) {
                var name = this.name;
                scrollToAnchor(name);
                e.preventDefault();
                var target = $('a[name="#' + this.name + '"]');
                
                target.animate({ backgroundColor: "#C4E9FE" }, 800);
                }, function () {
                    target.animate({ backgroundColor: "#ffffff" }, 800);
                });` and it says target is not defined...

Comment: How do you identify the element to scroll to? use the same type of selector for `target`.

Comment: Aha...I found the issue...I'm calling it by name, here's the result for anyone else who may have this issue in the future: `$(".app").click(function (e) {
                var name = this.name;
                scrollToAnchor(name);
                var target = $('a[name="' + this.name + '"]');
                target.animate({
                    backgroundColor: "#C4E9FE"
                },
          2500,
          function () {
              target.animate({ backgroundColor: "#fff" }, 2500);
          }
        );

                e.preventDefault();
            });`

Answer (score 0):

Since you know the *resultant* anchor tag's `id` (assuming this since by default when you scroll to `#link` hash, it means you scroll to an element with id = 'link'). You can animate it using:

```
var name = this.name;
scrollToAnchor(name);
$('#'+name).animate(...);
e.preventDefault();
```

If you need to target by name, you can do:

```
$('[name="'+name+'"']).animate(...);
```

Comment: but that is the issue, the resultant anchor tag has no id, just a name.

Comment: I think you'll need to specify the tag because the link and the anchor have the same name, you don't want to animate both.